# Polymer camelCase attributes

Tags: attributes, polymer

I'm writing a wrapper around a js library with Polymer components. Basically, I need to be able to assign attributes to a component, and forward them to an instance of a js object.

The problem is that Polymer (or webcomponents in general?) forces attribute names to be lowercase.

Declaring the element

`<some-element fooBar="baz"></some-element>`

Generic change listener

```
attributeChanged: function(attrName, oldVal, newVal){
    // attrName -> foobar, which is not a member of someInstance
    this.someInstance[attrName] = newVal;
}
```

Is there some way to get the camel-cased name? Maybe I can create a hash from the `publish` object on the prototype... but how do I reference that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! `publish` is actually available on the component instance! This allows me to grab the names and make a map from lowercase to camelcase.

```
var map = {};
Object.keys(this.publish).forEach(function(key){
    map[key.toLowerCase()] = key;
});
```