# Polymer & D3: How to send JSON from element attribute to template

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, polymer

I'm new to polymer and I'm trying to integrate D3 with it. I modified an existing Gist but I'm a bit stumped. 
I'm trying to pass some JSON from Polymer element attribute (`barData`) in HTML to the polymer template. The JSON is being passed as a `String` and parsed into a computed property (`data`). I've placed some default values into the `barData` property but want these overwritten each time a new element is created, with the `barData` attribute. This does not work. I created another attribute called `test` that just passes a string to a test property that is displayed in a paragraph. This works fine? Am i missing something obvious?

`index.HTML`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/bar-chart2.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--creates chart but with template data set although the test attribute does work-->
    <bar-chart2 barData='[{"letter":"C","frequency":".76"},{"letter":"D","frequency":".03"}]' test="CHEEP"></bar-chart2>
    <!--creates chart but with template data set-->
    <!--<bar-chart2 barData="http://codepen.io/superpikar/pen/kcJDf.js"></bar-chart2>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

`bar-chart2.html`:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="bar-chart2" attributes="barData">
    <template>
        <div id="chart" class="poly-bars">{{barData}}<p>{{test}}</p></div>
<!--the chart will use the new data after input but I want it to happen on create -->
        <div>
            <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{barData}}" placeholder="paste data here">
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        function Bars(opts) {
            opts = opts || {};
            var margin = opts.margin || {
              top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 40
            };
            var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
            var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            var title = opts.title || 'Bar Chart';

            var formatPercent = d3.format('.0%');

            var xValue = function(d) {
                    return d.letter;
                }, // data -> value
                xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1), // value -> display
                xMap = function(d) {
                    return xScale(xValue(d));
                }, // data -> display
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom');

            var yValue = function(d) {
                    return d.frequency;
                }, // data -> value
                yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
                yMap = function(d) {
                    return yScale(yValue(d));
                }, // data -> display
                yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left').tickFormat(formatPercent);

            function type(d) {
                d.frequency = +d.frequency;
                return d;
            }

            function bars(selection) {
                selection.each(function(d, i) {

                    var el = d3.select(this);

                    el.selectAll('svg').remove();

                    var svg = el.append('svg')
                        .attr('title', title)
                        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

                    xScale.domain(d.map(xValue));
                    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(d, yValue)]);

                    svg.append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'x axis')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
                        .call(xAxis);

                    svg.append('g')
                        .attr('class', 'y axis')
                        .call(yAxis)
                        .append('text')
                        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
                        .attr('y', 6)
                        .attr('dy', '.71em')
                        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                        .text('Frequency');

                    svg.selectAll('.bar')
                        .data(d)
                        .enter().append('rect')
                        .attr('class', 'bar')
                        .attr('x', xMap)
                        .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand)
                        .attr('y', yMap)
                        .attr('height', function(d) {
                            return height - yMap(d);
                        });
                });
            }

            return bars;
        }

        Polymer({
            is: 'bar-chart2',
            properties: {
                test: {
                    type: String,
                    value: "BOOM"
                },
                barData: {
                    type: String,
                    value: '[{"letter":"A","frequency":".08167"},{"letter":"B","frequency":".01492"}]',
                    reflect: true,
                    notify: true
                },
                width: Number,
                height: {
                    type: Number,
                    value: 400
                },
                data: {
                    type: Array,
                    computed: '_parse(barData)'
                }
            },
            _parse: JSON.parse,

            observers: [
                'dataChanged(data)'
            ],

            created: function() {
                this.bars = new Bars(this);
            },

            dataChanged: function() {
                this._draw();
            },

            _draw: function() {
                if (!this.data) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!this.elem) {
                    return;
                }

                d3.select(this.elem)
                    .datum(this.data).call(this.bars);
            },

            ready: function() {
                this.elem = this.$.chart;
                this._draw();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you trying to use? Looking at your code it appears as though you are trying to mix version 1.0 and 0.8 or less.

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm using latest version 1.0 but finding it difficult to find examples of it with d3

Comment: Ok for starters, you are not declaring your element in the correct way for version 1.0. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html) for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I made changes to reflect 1.0 declarations but the problem is more related to the data bindings. I can't figure out why the string attribute "test" gets passed ok but the string "barData" doesn't? The string works fine when its written straight into the template.

Answer (score 2):

Change `barData` to `bar-data`;

> When mapping attribute names to property names:
>
> 1. Attribute names are converted to lowercase property names. For example, the attribute `firstName` maps to `firstname`.
> 2. Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the dashes. For example, the attribute `first-name` maps to `firstName`.

Please view the [Polymer doc here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping) .

Answer (score 1):

Change `barData` to `bardata` (lowercase) everywhere and it will work.

Comment: THANK YOU! At first I thought you were joking. but it appears that web component attributes have to be all lowercase. more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178675/polymer-camelcase-attributes . This was totally wrecking my head.